# Is there a way to access a nestJS app deployed on Heroku with the R10 error?

Tags: node.js, heroku, nestjs

I deployed my nestJS app on heroky `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`. I changed the port to which the app listen to 5000 but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put `process.env.PORT` into `await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);`